# Layout for angular2 html

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Polymer has a class-based layout system as shown below

### .html

```
<template>
    <div class = "layout vertical main-container">
      <input type='text'>
      <div>I am below the input</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

What mechanism exist for layout when developing with angular2-dart?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing integrated in Angular2 yet. I'm sure Angular2 material will provide some CSS to make this easy. Besides that you can use any CSS library (depending on the view encapsulation mode you are using http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html)
I have yet to test if Polymer style modules can be used in Angular2. With full shadow DOM, they might work.

Comment: Thanks. Currently [https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular2_rbi](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular2_rbi) provide Material Design Directives that can be used in angular2. I am trying them at the moment. However, using them might not be the easiest thing if there is no layout.

Comment: You can also copy the Polymer CSS source and use it in Angular2 if you are used to them.

Comment: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/classes/iron-flex-layout.html

Comment: iron-flex-layout will not work. It converts the material design elements of MDL-lite directives back to conventional widgets.

Comment: I don't understand that comment, but I have no knowledge of MDL, but doesn't MDL itself provide such layout styles?

Comment: I will explain. A material-design text input that has a single line is converted to a classical text input with a rectangular box. Buttons are stretched to fill the entire width of the browser when they are placed vertically

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with angular using dart, but AFAIK, [Angular flex layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki) is the best alternative in most cases for angular using typescript.